# ClojureScript deep equal for JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, interop, clojurescript, deepequals

I've ran into the problem how to compare two JavaScript objects for deep equality in ClojureScript, because (= var1 var2 var3...) only works on Clojure/ClojureScript collections and numbers.

```
(= (js-obj "a" 1) (js-obj "a" 1)) ;; => false
```

While I wrote this question I found the solution... but I'll ask and answer it maybe help others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the "=" function can compare ClojureScript collections, one immediate solutions should be:

```
(= (js->clj (js-obj "a" 1)) (js->clj (js-obj "a" 1))) ;; => true
```

Which is ugly, and does not work on instanced objects like.:

```
(= (js->clj (js/THREE.Vector3. 10 20 30)) (js->clj (js/THREE.Vector3. 10 20 30))) ;; => false
```

The most reliable solution is using the [goog.equals](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.object.html) method from [Google's Closure Library](https://github.com/google/closure-library).

```
(ns my.name-space
  (:import goog.object)
  (:require [cljsjs.three]))

(.equals goog.object (js/THREE.Vector3. 10 20 30) (js/THREE.Vector3. 10 20 30))) ;; => true
```

In general Google's Closure Library has robust solutions for handling plain JavaScript.

Comment: That's not a true deep equals though: `(goog.object/equals #js {"a" #js [1]} #js {"a" #js [1]}) => false`.